# Sorting alphanumeric strings

Tags: string-manipulation, sorting

Say I have

```
strings = {"a16", "b22", "a8", "c1", "b18", "b2", "a1"};
```

`Sort@strings` gives `{"a1", "a16", "a8", "b18", "b2", "b22", "c1"}`, but I'd like to obtain `{"a1", "a8", "a16", "b2", "b18", "b22", "c1"}`. What's the shortes and most elegant way to do so? It could be done with `StringSplit`, `ToExpression`, `Ordering` etc., but this all looks like an exaggeration; I expected MMA to have something like `SortBy[strings,AlphaNumericalOrder]`...

Comment: Perhaps this works: `SortBy[strings, Characters]`. Edit: it doesn't.

Comment: @march It works for cases when all strings in `strings` start with the same letter, e.g. `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define:

```
alphanumeric = StringReplace[d:DigitCharacter.. :> FromDigits[d]];
```

then we can write:

```
alphanumeric["a16"]

(* "a" ~~ 16 *)
```

and thus:

```
SortBy[strings, alphanumeric]

(* {"a1", "a8", "a16", "b2", "b18", "b22", "c1"} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Narrow but FWIW:

```
strings[[Ordering[(Characters /@ 
      strings) /. {{x_, y_} :> {x, 0, y}}]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not too elegant, but `SortBy[]` with two custom tie-breaking functions does the job:

```
SortBy[strings, {First[StringCases[#, LetterCharacter ..]] &, 
                 FromDigits[First[StringCases[#, DigitCharacter ..]]] &}]
   {"a1", "a8", "a16", "b2", "b18", "b22", "c1"}
```

Answer (score 1):

A hokey way to do it would be to add a zero before the single digits.

Start by defining a simple function:

```
f = StringReplace[#, (x : LetterCharacter ~~ y : DigitCharacter ~~ 
      EndOfString) :> x <> "0" <> y] &
```

Then

```
SortBy[strings, f]
```

> `{"a1", "a8", "a16", "b2", "b18", "b22", "c1"}`

This naturally would have to be expanded for strings in which the digits are larger than 100.