# Simple method to sort versions

Tags: list-manipulation, text, sorting

The goal is to sort long lists of versions. For example:

**Input**

```
versions={"openmpi@1.8.4", "openmpi@1.10", "openmpi@1.10.6", "openmpi@2.0.2",
"openmpi@1.6", "openmpi@1.6.2", "openmpi@2.0"}
```

**Desired Output**

```
SortedVersions={"openmpi@2.0.2", "openmpi@2.0","openmpi@1.10.6", "openmpi@1.10", "openmpi@1.8.4", "openmpi@1.6.2", 
    "openmpi@1.6"}
```

Assume the package (here openmpi) does not change, and the format is `package@version` with version being `n.n.n` or `n.n`

My method is very cumbersome. Surely some Mathematica wizardry can bring relief.

Bonus: allow the option to sort descending (shown here) or ascending.

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128485/sorting-alphanumeric-strings).

Comment: @corey979: Yes, this is related. I'm struggling with the `n.n.n` or `n.n` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
versionList = ToExpression@StringSplit[Last@StringSplit[#, "@"], "."] &;

Reverse@SortBy[versions, versionList]
(* {"openmpi@2.0.2", "openmpi@1.10.6", "openmpi@1.8.4", "openmpi@1.6.2", "openmpi@2.0", "openmpi@1.10", "openmpi@1.6"} *)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SortBy[ 
 PadRight[#, 3] & @* StringCases[n : DigitCharacter .. :> ToExpression[n]]
] @ versions // Reverse
```

Comment: Probably the safest method, as opposed to using `ToExpression` on random strings (like `Quit`).

Comment: @CarlWoll yep, though I did assume there are no numbers except in the version part.

Comment: @CarlWoll The Paclet Manager uses ToExpression for version parsing. Imagine what you could do with a simple PacletInfo file ...

Comment: @Szabolcs https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172553/5478

Answer (score 6):

```
versions[[Ordering @ - PadRight@ToExpression[Rest /@ StringSplit[versions, "@" | "."]]]]
```

> {"openmpi@2.0.2", "openmpi@2.0", "openmpi@1.10.6", "openmpi@1.10", 
>   "openmpi@1.8.4", "openmpi@1.6.2", "openmpi@1.6"}

Answer (score 5):

```
Reverse@SortBy[
 versions, 
 PadRight[ToExpression[
  StringSplit[StringDrop[#, StringPosition[#, "@"][[-1, 1]]], "."]],
  3] &
]
```

> {"openmpi@2.0.2", "openmpi@2.0", "openmpi@1.10.6", "openmpi@1.10", 
>   "openmpi@1.8.4", "openmpi@1.6.2", "openmpi@1.6"}

Comment: Ah, my approach was very similar but `SortBy` is definitely better here.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to create a '*complete*' function with input checking, options and basic error messaging; I was going for a more *contained* experience but I think it got a bit out of hand; anyway, here's my take:

```
(* try and localize symbols *)
Block[{m, n, checkVersions, checkQ, ascend},

  (* 'pattn' *should* match the 'package@version' strings *)
  With[{pattn = StringExpression[LetterCharacter .., "@", m : StringExpression[DigitCharacter, "."] .., n : DigitCharacter ..]},

    (* 'checkVersions' works with 'checkQ' (see below) to validate input *)
    SetAttributes[checkVersions, Listable];

    checkVersions = Function[{version}, StringMatchQ[version, pattn], Listable];

    checkQ = Function[{versions}, And @@ checkVersions[versions]] /. OwnValues[checkVersions];

    (* 'rhs' extracts the version digits from an input string *)
    With[{rhs = Thread[ToExpression[PadRight[Join[StringSplit[#1, "."], {#2}], 3]]] &},

      (* 'ascend' sorts the input according to the version digits *)
      ascend = SortBy[#, (StringCases[#, pattn :> rhs[m, n]] &)] &;

      With[{checkVersionsQ = checkQ, sortVersionsAscending = ascend},

        (* 'sortVersions' is the callable function; option 'Ascending' controls how sorting is done *)
        Options[sortVersions] = {Ascending -> Automatic};

        sortVersions::srtvopterr = "Option value '`1`' is not recognised. Possible values for option 'Ascending' include 'True', 'False' and 'Automatic'.";

        sortVersions[versions_?checkVersionsQ, OptionsPattern[]] :=  With[{optval = OptionValue[Ascending]},

          If[

            MemberQ[{True, False, Automatic}, optval],

            Which[

              optval === Automatic || optval, sortVersionsAscending[versions],        

              Not[optval], Reverse[sortVersionsAscending[versions]]

             ],

            Message[sortVersions::srtvopterr, optval]

           ]


         ]

       ]

    ]

  ]

 ]
```

Evaluating the following lines of code

```
sortVersions[versions]
sortVersions[versions, Ascending -> Automatic]
sortVersions[versions, Ascending -> True]
sortVersions[versions, Ascending -> False]
sortVersions[versions, Ascending -> WrongOptionValue]
```

produces the following output

> ```
> {"openmpi@1.6", "openmpi@1.6.2", "openmpi@1.8.4", 
>      "openmpi@1.10", "openmpi@1.10.6", "openmpi@2.0", "openmpi@2.0.2"}
> {"openmpi@1.6", "openmpi@1.6.2", "openmpi@1.8.4", 
>      "openmpi@1.10", "openmpi@1.10.6", "openmpi@2.0", "openmpi@2.0.2"}
> {"openmpi@1.6", "openmpi@1.6.2", "openmpi@1.8.4", 
>      "openmpi@1.10", "openmpi@1.10.6", "openmpi@2.0", "openmpi@2.0.2"}
> {"openmpi@2.0.2", "openmpi@2.0", "openmpi@1.10.6", 
>     "openmpi@1.10", "openmpi@1.8.4", "openmpi@1.6.2", "openmpi@1.6"}
> ```
>
> [image]

A last minute though was to provide an extra 'Option' that deals with the possible issue of a variable length for the *version* digits (eg more than three groups) but I didn't want to make it more complicated than it already is...

hope it's helpfull

Answer (score 2):

It seems like all you need is a general-purpose **number-aware sorting function**. Here is my implementation of it:

```
NaturalSort::usage = "Sorting function for number-aware sorting. Use with Sort.";
NaturalSort[a_String, b_String] := OrderedQ[
  StringSplit[#, d : DigitCharacter .. :> ToExpression@d, All] & /@ {a, b},
  ListOrder]
```

`NaturalSort` splits the string into a list of `DigitCharacter`s and non-`DigitCharacters`. Then it checks whether the two lists are in order.

The helper function `ListOrder` determines whether two lists of **unequal length** are in order. I needed this because with `Order[list1, list2]` the shorter list always comes first.
`ListOrder` pads the shorter list with `Null`, maps `Order` to all pairs, and reverses the order if one element is `Null` (I have defined that `Null` always comes first but `Order` disagrees, hence the workaround).

```
ListOrder[a_List, b_List] := SelectFirst[
  MapThread[
   Order[#1, #2] * If[FreeQ[{#1, #2}, Null], 1, -1] &,

   PadRight[#, Max[Length /@ {a, b}], Null] & /@ {a, b}
   ],
  # != 0 &,
  0
]
```

`NaturalSort` can then be used as the sorting function for `Sort`:

```
In[]:= Sort[versions, NaturalSort]

(* {"openmpi@1.6", "openmpi@1.6.2", "openmpi@1.8.4", "openmpi@1.10", "openmpi@1.10.6", "openmpi@2.0", "openmpi@2.0.2"} *)
```